# Shared memory or named pipes in ram?

Tags: c++, c, memory, pipe, shared

I want to communicate between two different programs. A modded ambilight program which outputs led information and my own program that reads this information.

I read about named pipes and shared memory. But for me it is not clear where the data is stored. Due to the fact that i will exchange a lot of data i do not want to write this data to disk every time. I am using a raspberry Pi and the sd card should last for some more time ;)

So the basic question is: with what methode can i exchange information to the other end without writing to the disk? I am not sure if shared memory is written to ram, i want to make this clear.
As another idea i read about is /dev/shm which should be a ram disk. Can i also use named pipes for this location and will the information than be saved in ram?

whats the best way to go? thanks :)

Comment: altought a very complex solution - is TCP/IP communication (establishing a client/server communication between the two apps) a valid solution for you? other than that, the named pipes is the infrastructure exactly for this kind of tasks

Comment: A named pipe is probably the easiest variant. Then there is unix domain sockets. And then there is always tcp/ip, as mentioned. It does not really matter where you put the named pipe or unix domain socket, only the filename and a few flags is ever written to the filesystem.  /dev/shm is very convenient if you want to shuffle large amounts of data around (it's significantly easier to use than "classic" shm).

Comment: @NirMH What are advantages of TCP/IP versus pipes or UNIX domain sockets, provided that communication will happen between processes on the same machine?

Comment: @el.pescado: TCP/IP is not writing to the disk - the data is trasfered as byte stream via TCP/IP network layer - i think the lowest layer will be TCP (not going down to the NIC itself) but i don't fully sure about it

Comment: @NirMH I mean, why use TCP/IP (which involves, albeit behind-the-scenes, splitting your data to packets, prepending with headers, computing checksums etc) when you can use e.g. UNIX-domain sockets?

Comment: Okay i started with named pipes but i had the problem that i need a pipe back for a "received" signal. otherwise i would have a problem if the reader is too slow to read the data. So named pipes work more like a serial signal, that wasnt clear for me first.

I tried shared memory then and this works perfectly! I have no problem if the data updates while reading as long as the byte itself doesnt get destroyed/changed. But i testet that with a stresstest and it seems the bits are always stable. so this is my way to go. galileo books has a pretty nice tutorial (at least in german).

Comment: And the memory problem: i am an Arduino user too. i just need at the very maximum 255*3+1 byte :D less than 1kb should be fine for the pi.
Thx for the help

Comment: @el.pescado: i'm not saying TCP/IP is better - it is an option to consider and you're right, there are many performance impact operations happening in the background.

Answer (score 7):

> I read about named pipes and shared memory. But for me it is not clear
>   where the data is stored.

In both cases, data is stored in memory (named pipes look like they reside on filesystem, but actual data is stored on memory).

What method is better, it depends on actual application. Pipes have fairly limited buffer (most likely `64kb`) and writing to it will block when buffer is full. Shared memory can be arbitrarily large, but on the downside, shared memory is, well, just like that - plain memory. You have to take care about synchronization etc yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Shared memory and named pipes (and unix domain sockets) IPC won't write to your sdcard unless you allocate more memory than the available physical RAM which is either 256MB or 512MB depending on your raspberrypi model. If you do so it will start swapping and will probably slow down.