# Shared memory, pipes, or sockets, with which one, data sharing between two proecesses can be faster and safer?

Tags: windows, sockets, visual-c++, pipe, shared-memory

Inside our project (windows specific with VC++), we intended to share data between two processes. Indeed different approaches have been acquired to do the task, namely establishing `pipes` in between, `mapping a shared memory` where both processes can **MapView** it into their address space for usage, and of course, creation of `TCP connection`. There is this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262250/shared-memory-or-named-pipes-in-ram) which explains about differences, but my query is specifically what has been written in the title of my question. Which way suite `faster` data sharing between two processes while `security` and `data integrity` is demanded in the first place?

By security, I mean hiding the transfer as much as possible from all other processes on system and data integrity means lesser number of attempts to deliver a defined number of bytes as payload to the other side.